# It is possible to make a slide overlay page transition in sveltekit with barbajs

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to make a simple slide transition in sveltekit when switching between routes.

The effect consist a overlay `div`, when route is changing, the overlay shows from bottom of the screen, it stays full screen for 1s, then moves up to reveal the next route.

A library for doing this is barba.js but so far i cannot implement it, when i import the lib i get document errors etc.

If anyone has done it before please share the simpliest solution.